# Scrapy as anacron job - How can I change the owner of the resulting csv files?

Tags: permissions, cron, scrapy

I have a scrapy scraper that I can schedule using anachron without a problem but the resulting files are owned by root

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/scraper/bin/activate
cd /home/myusername/workspace/scraper/scraper
scrapy crawl scraper
```

The script is run as root through anacron

It works fine, however the resulting .csv files created by the scraper are owned by root

The file name is appended by the current date.

What is the most straightforward way to have the resulting .csv files    owned by myusername ?

Comment: Is this script run as `root`?

Comment: Yes, script is run as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples way is to add on the end of your script line like:

```
chown myusername <resulting .csv>
```

This will change the ownership to user `myusername`. In case of need you can use wildcard. If the archive is not in the current directory you should defile full path to the file.